# How can I find the name of the person ranked 1?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

What I'm trying to do is find the name of the person who is ranked number 1 in the table shown below. I have tried `=LOOKUP` and `=VLOOKUP` but I get an error saying that a result can't be found, even though it's obviously there. I assume that I'm either using the wrong function or just not using it right.

I tried `=VLOOKUP(1;D2:H19;1)` and `=LOOKUP(1;D2:H19;1)` but neither seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the behaviour you desire:

```
=INDEX(D2:D,MATCH(1,H2:H,0))
```

### Explanation

`=VLOOKUP` can only be used to find values to the right of a search key. To find values to the left of a search key, use a combination of `=INDEX` and `=MATCH`.

The `=MATCH` function searches a specified range for a specified value and returns the relative position of the value in that range. In this case, the value to search for is `1`, the range to search through is `H2:H`, and the `0` at the end specifies that the range is not sorted in any way.

The `=INDEX` function returns the contents of a cell within a range having a specified row and column offset. In this case, the range is `D2:D`, and the row is whichever row is returned by `=MATCH`. `=INDEX` could take a third argument if it was desired to specify a row offset as well, but that is not necessary here.

Functions used:

- [=INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [=MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You sort your ascending order based on rank then return your desired data using `INDEX()` function. Try-

```
=INDEX(SORT(D2:H500,5,1),1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=vlookup(1,{H2:H19, D2:D19},2)
```

Since `vlookup` only searches the 1st column of the input range, to use it, you need to flip the columns by composing a local array: `{H2:H19, D2:D19}`.

`{}` means concatenation. `,` in it means horizontal concatenation. With that, the rank column is now the 1st column in the input of `vlookup` and now `vlookup` works.

With our local array, the 2nd column are the names and therefore index should be 2.

Also note the use of comma to separate function inputs.

Answer (score 1):

your VLOOKUP formula should look like:

```
=VLOOKUP(1, {H2:H19, D2:D19}, 2, 0)
```

also try just:

```
=FILTER(D:D; H:H=1)
```

or:

```
=SORTN(D:D; 1; 1; H:H; 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query (usefull in case of ex aequo)

```
=query(D2:H,"select D where H=1",0)
```